# Wordpress REST API - Change excerpt length just for data that I am pulling not entire site

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I am using php to pull in posts from a WP site using the REST API, and it gives you both options to use full content, and excerpt. Although the excerpt is just too short for what I am using it for. I also don't want to change the global excerpt length, just for this one project using the REST API. Is there anyway to change the excerpted length via REST API and not effect the rest of the website?

The only thing I can think of is truncating the full content via small script when pulling in the data from the REST API and creating my own "read more" link using other variable that are accessible like source_url.

I am new to REST API in wordpress, but I don't see anything related to it in the official documentation, so wasn't sure if someone knew a good trick, or if I'll just have to go the manual route. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt length is just used to limit the length of the output in your template. So you should handle it's length in your WordPress template, more specifically in your `functions.php` not in your REST API.

See here for more info:
http://smallenvelop.com/limit-post-excerpt-length-in-wordpress/

Unfortunately there's no way to set the excerpt length for your pulling request, like `$api-getposts(300)` or something like that, since the excerpt is strongly tied to your WordPress site.

However, you could register an api-callback on your WP-site, which sets the excerpt to a higher value, pull the data, and reset it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length

Just wrap this function in a `register_rest_route`

So your request would look something like this

```
$api->setExcerpt(300);
$api->getData();
$api->setExcerpt(100);
```

Comment: No, I understand that. I am pulling data from Wordpress to an external site. I don't want to change the excerpt length in the Wordpress site as the default works well for the design. However, on the external site, I wanted a longer length of an excerpt. What I have done in the interim, and also if there is no way to do it, I have just run the full post output and am truncating it myself and just adding my own "read more" link.

Comment: Updated my answer ;-)